# How to create scene template?

Tags: unity

I'm creating a game with `Unity 3D`, where has many levels, and I want create a button in all levels, to back to level menu.

Is possible can I create a "scene template" where I can only change one time, and all level scenes inherit template changes?

Comment: Usually this would be done with a prefab. You'd take the content you want to have in every scene, parent it to a single object, and drag it into your project window to save it as a prefab. Then you can drag that object into each scene to populate them with the same content. Changing the prefab in the project window or hitting "Apply" will propagate the changes to all scenes. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("myscene",  SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive);`
```

to load scene "templates" for things like pause menu, HUD, inventory, etc.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html